# Django template - check if field has value in it or empty if ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-template-filters

This seems rather simple but I am not able to figure out a good solution from SO or Django docs (using Django 1.10)

I am fetching a model object in the template and displaying only those fields that have values (i.e not blank or null) or not empty if ManyToManyField.

I am not able to figure out a good way to do it apart from just using many `if` and `else`'s to check the field type and then run the corresponding `if` condition.

`{% if model_name.field_name %}` always returns `true` for `ManytoManyField`s (since its a `ManyRelatedManager`)

`{% if model_name.field_name|length > 0 %}` always returns `false` for `ManytoManyField`s

`{% if model_name.field_name.all %}` may work fine for `ManyToManyFields` but not for others (like `CharField`)

Is there a one way to check whether a field has some usable value inside it (whether `ManytoManyField` or a simple `CharField`)? I can resort to using multiple `if-else` to check the field type first and then running the corresponding check, but it feels counter-intuitive to do so since this feels like a common use case to justify a template tag.

Comment: If you need such logic, maybe it would be better to put it into your `views.py`. The associated objects from a ManyToManyField or a ForeignKeyField should be called with some method of the RelatedManager: `all`, or maybe `filter`.

Comment: @cezar - thanks, I moved the logic to views.py. Posted my final code as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

@cezar's advice made sense so I moved the logic to `views.py` (after all, the logic of whether to show a value or not, will fall in the what-to-show bucket and hence goes to the view instead of how-to-show in the template)

Also, instead of returning a model object to the template, now returning a dict with only the relevant values in it. ManyToManyFields (if not empty) appear as lists within the dict.

```
for field in school._meta.get_fields(): # where school is the model object

    #checking if field type is m2m
    if (field.get_internal_type() == 'ManyToManyField'):
        if getattr(school,field.name).exists():
             school_display[field.name] = [k.name for k in getattr(school, field.name).all()]

    #checking if field has choices (so we could send the display name)
    elif field.choices:
        func_name_to_display = 'get_' + field.name + '_display'
        #note the '()' at the end, below. getattr(a,b) is equivalent to a.b so we need to add a '()' at the end since its a function
        school_display[field.name] = getattr(school,func_name_to_display)()

    #just returning the value (if not empty) in other cases
    else:   
        field_value = getattr(school,field.name)
        if (field_value and field_value!='None'):
             school_display[field.name] = field_value

return render(request, 'detail.html', {'school_display' : school_display})
```

I am glad I did this because I discovered, during the process, calls to two other methods on the model object that would ideally belong to views.py, and moved them as well.

Happy to learn if the above approach could be improved.

Answer (score 2):

You could make it cleaner by using `get_fields`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model

So in your case it would look something like this (this is pseudo code):

```
{% for field in Model._meta.get_fields() %}
    {% if field.get_internal_type() == "ManyToManyField" %}
        ...  # render m2m, here you could use gettatr
    {% else %}
        ...  # render regular field, here you could use gettatr
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I also agree with @cezar's comment that you should move something like this into `views.py`

Comment: Thanks @Sardorbek - did you mean using the corresponding logic for get_fields(), getattr(), get_internal_type() etc. in the template somehow? I have posted my code - now moved the logic to views.py and interestingly the final code looks similar to your pseudo code for the template, hence upvoting

Comment: @Anupam yes, it could be used in templates, but I strongly suggest doing this in views.py, as you did.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a template filter, it will be quiet obvious what it should look like:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def is_not_empty(field):
    try:
        return field.count()
    except (AttributeError, TypeError):
        return field
```